# Opening a link to an intranet site when function disabled in IE

Tags: javascript, asp.net, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-8

So recently I have been tasked with making standard hyperlinks work on a website that open pages on an intranet site. This works in Chrome on the same environment but not in IE 8. This is the clients current supported browser.

The issue is that in IE the setting *Websites in less privileged web content zone can navigate into this zone.* is disabled by policy settings, so if you attempt to open a link from the site to an intranet site, in IE 8 you get an Access Denied error.

Now obviously given this is disabled and can't be enabled in the short term (if at all) and given that providing them a link to copy is not an agreeable solution, I have been asked to see what is possible.

One url points to the sitemap of the intranet site. I also do not have access to the intranet site code.

Things I have tried:

1. Using javascript opening a window - Access Denied
2. Using javascript to open a blank window and injecting javascript to update the window.location, this also resulted in an Accesss Denied because the new window appears to be on the original domain (rather than blank).
3. IIS Reverse proxy, clicking on the link appears to host the intranet site from within the current site. This worked well but two features failed to work on the intranet site due to internal redirects, so wasn't feasible.
4. Performing a redirect from a mapped internal link to the required intranet link at IIS and .Net Controller levels, both of these fail as redirects are disabled on the client machine.
5. IFrame, eurgh - Access Denied

So my question is given that the feature is disabled by IE can any one think of the way around this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just in-case anyone finds this useful. I managed to resolve this using the IIS Reverse proxy. There was an issue with some internal redirects not being handled, which was under a different sub folder to the rest of the site. But the main issue I had in getting this to work was that calls to .aspx files on the external site were actually being caught by the internal site's page handler, which meant that the rewrite rules for certain calls were getting handled as pages internally and returning a 404 page.

As our internal site uses razor under MVC, the page handler isn't used, so I was luckily able to remove the page handlers within the web.config. If this wasn't the case, I would have had to reorder the handlers so that the redirect rules handled the call before the handler.